# Pivot Table with Additional Columns

Tags: matlab, pivot-table

Let's have a 2D double array such as:

```
% Data: ID, Index, Weight, Category
A0=[1 1121 204 1;...
    2 2212 112 1;...
    3 2212 483 3;...
    4 4334 233 1;...
    5 4334 359 2;...
    6 4334 122 3 ];
```

I am needing to pivot / group by the rows with the highest Weights, for each given Index, which can be achieved with any [Pivot Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) | Group By functionality (such as  [`pivottable`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30547-pivottable), SQL GROUP BY or MS Excel PivotTable)

```
% Current Result
A1=pivottable(A0,[2],[],[3],{@max}); % Pivot Table
A1=cell2mat(A1); % Convert to array

>>A1=[1121 204;...
      2212 483;...
      4334 359 ]
```

How should I proceed if I need to recover also the ID and the Category columns?

```
% Required Result
>>A1=[1 1121 204 1;...
      3 2212 483 3;...
      5 4334 359 2 ];
```

The syntax is Matlab, but a solution involving other languages (Java, SQL) can be acceptable, due they can be transcribed into Matlab.

Comment: If there is a tie, should you keep all maximizing rows? The first one?

Comment: I dont have any specification for that case. Could be the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) with an anonymous function as follows.

```
grouping_col = 2; % Grouping column
maximize_col = 3; % Column to maximize 
[~, ~, group_label] = unique(A0(:,grouping_col));
result = splitapply(@(x) {x(x(:,maximize_col)==max(x(:,maximize_col)),:)}, A0, group_label);
result = cell2mat(result); % convert to matrix
```

**How it works**: the anonymous function `@(x) {x(x(:,maximize_col)==max(···),:)}` is called by [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) once for each group. The function is provided as input a submatrix containing all rows with the same value of the column with index `grouping_col`. What this function then does is keep all rows that maximize the column with index `maximize_col`, and pack that into a cell. The result is then converted to matrix form by [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

---

With the above solution, if there are several maximizing rows for each group **all** of them are produced. To keep only the **first** one, replace the last line by

```
result = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) c(1,:), result, 'uniformoutput', false));
```

**How it works**: this uses [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the anonymous function `@(c) c(1,:)` to the content of each cell. The function simply keeps the first row. Alternatively, to keep the **last** row use `@(c) c(end,:)`. The result is then converted to matrix form using `cell2mat` again.